# Updating modal with proper image

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to achieve is getting the `modal_img` to appear in the `modal` when it opens.  But I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
<img class="modal_click" src="images/4.jpg">
      <div class="modal" onclick="modal_click;">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">X</span>
            <img class="modal_img" src="images/4.jpg">
          </div>
      </div>
    <img class="modal_click" src="images/gandhi.jpg">
      <div class="modal" onclick="modal_click;">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">X</span>
            <img class="modal_img" src="images/gandhi.jpg">
          </div>
      </div>
```

At this point once I iterate through all the images I want to update the DOM to include the correct image.

```
for(var i = 0; i < modal_click.length; i++)
  {  
      modal_click[i].onclick = function()
      {
          modal.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: for starters, "modal_click;" should be "modal_click();" and you are using the same name for something else too -- probably should change it.

Comment: I do name things weird I’ll agree with you there.  The onclick event is no longer valid I just haven’t removed it from the html.